# Reading and analyzing a file: should I use a list or a dictionary for this format?

Tags: python, file

Here is the file format.  the first row is the unique column identifier.  The first column is the time in 15 minute increments.

[image: image of the text file that I need to read and analyze]

What is the best way to read this text file and analyze the data?

Comment: You might want to have a look at pandas https://pandas.pydata.org

Answer (score 1):

I think Pandas DataFrame is best choice for your data.

Try this code.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("file_name.csv", index_col = 0)
```

Comment: Thank you, Gilseung Ahn.  I am going to try !!

Answer (score 0):

Pandas is really good for things like that, but if you'd rather use lists and dictionaries, I would recommend making lists of Dictionaries.
After parsing through your file, you could make it look like this:

```
my_list = [
    {
        "Name": "NBL",
        715: 8,
        730: 16
     },
    {
        "Name": "NBT",
        715: 3,
        730: 5
    }
]
```